# Saving and Restoring a Canvas on A Individual User Basis

Tags: php, customization, custom-field

I’m a little lost and not sure where to begin. I’m not necessarily looking for a complete solution, just a guide to the right direction.

I want to have:
    ⁃   a page with the drawing application that users can visit freely; would be blank on load
    ⁃   A page with saved canvases, that I can click to open in page 1

I’m not sure what I need to do in order to save and restore canvases in this way; the main goal is that it be on a user basis, e.g. each user would have their own “creations” list page and not be able to see each other’s work.

I currently have the application; it’s mainly JS and HTML- what I’m struggling with is how to go about saving the canvas’ ‘dataToURL’ to the WordPress site on an individual user basis as described above.

Can anyone please help me fill the blanks? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post some of your code and be more explicit about the problem you have?  It would help if you could show how this was a WordPress related question too.  Thanks.